# 100% height for body and its child elements

Tags: html, css

I am specifying a background color for the `body` which displays up to a certain distance only. I need it to be full height and for its child elements too. One of its child elements has `border-right` which also needs to show over the full screen height.

My CSS looks like(sample one) better check my demo

[demo page](http://www.mediaserveit.com/demo/vivek/buildmysite_dashboard/project_details.html)

```
   html,body {
         height: 100%; 
         background-color: #fefefe;
    }
    .cover {
         height: 100%;
    }
    .left_side {
        float: left; 
        height: 100%;
        border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
        width: 31%;  
    }
```

and html is

```
     <body>
         <div class="cover">
            <div class="left_side">
            </div>
         </div>
      </body>
```

and the  bgcolor and childs border seems up-to some limited distance only like
       [image]
what is that problem guys i need that background and border as 100% height.

Comment: your html is missing html-tags wooha :D add them and try to set html,body { height:100%;margin:0;padding:0;} ...also theres is much more3 visible on the page than you provided via code, so there is something ovverriding your styles

Comment: @johnSmith i never missed to put html tags to my html..the code gave above is sample one

Comment: Don't give `height: 100%` to body or html.

Comment: @Mr_Green Oh thanks! then what is that fix to do for this case

Comment: @VIVEkUI nothing.. `height: 100%` limits the body/html to not to grow its height more than the document/screen(which is parent) height.

Comment: @Mr_Green so it's better to add height to its child.well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove height:100% from your body and html style.

Instead of having a border set to the left container, try setting the border on the content container instead.

your css would be something like:

```
.large-9 .columns .right_side{border-left:1px solid #333;}
```

the left column is currently set to 100% and renders correctly. the problem is that it doesnt take into account the overflow content you cannot see, until you scroll. The other solution would be to absolute or fixed position the left container, and set its top and bottom values to 0.

css for that would be something like:

```
.left_side .full_height{position:fixed;top:0;bottom:0;width:200px;}
```

Here's a really basic layout with a fixed left column - http://jsfiddle.net/WAJtk/

and a version with a fixed header too - http://jsfiddle.net/WAJtk/1/

you might also like this pen - http://codepen.io/lukeocom/pen/KqAfG

Answer (score 0):

You could use absolute position and setting top and bottom:

```
body {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     bottom: 0;
}
```