# issue with setting min-height for a div before website load based on device height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This has to be the most simple case of css issue. But I could nt find a solution to this problem..

I have a main div which has min-height of certain value. Ive given the min-height in in `%` so there is no outer div and it will not show the `min-height`. if I give min - height in `px` , it will show up.

but I am trying to get the min-height to be 50% of window height and it could vary in each devices, so giving height in px is not an option for me... if I give `jquery.css()` function, and keep it `document.ready()` function, when the page starts loading, it will have zero height and it will come down to height that Ive specified and that doesnt look good in website..

Case 1 : http://jsfiddle.net/pT56y/

FIDDLE EXAMPLE

case 2 : http://jsfiddle.net/pT56y/2/
Is there a proper way to deal with this issue?

Comment: better put height 100%; to its parent element html, body... :)

Comment: but its not good to specify for body and html..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17964315/100-height-for-body-and-its-child-elements.

Comment: @VIVEkUI  http://jsfiddle.net/pT56y/2/ Check this case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in order to use a percentage height, the parent must have a set height (either in pixels or %):

```
body,html{
    height: 100%;
}
.container-fluid{
    background:#000000;
    width:100px;
    min-height:50%;    
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pT56y/2/)

Comment: Im using twiter bootstrap theme and if I give the percent height to body.. it will not take 100%;

Comment: this is just an example, if the div is nested you need to make sure ALL the parent divs have a set height, not just the `body,html`. Also you need to make sure bootstrap is not overriding your styling.